# How to use loops and conditionals in {} brackets?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not able to use if and for loop inside {} why ? Anything wrong?

```
sendTextMessageWithPromise(assignerID, `Value : ${if(x==0) console.log(x)}`)
```

Comment: `${}` expects an expression. `if` statements will not work. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @adiga I need value of x inside string but use of if statement outside sendTextMessageWithPromise() function is not printing any value because of node.js asynchronous behaviour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using conditionals inside template literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676974/using-conditionals-inside-template-literals)

Comment: Does `x` exist in the current scope? What does this have to with asynchronous function? It looks like `sendTextMessageWithPromise` takes 2 arguments. What should be the second argument's value when `x = 0` and `x != 0`?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon No, How can I use for loop ?

Comment: What `for` loop? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: You can't. Why would you want to?

Comment: You realize that your `console.log(x)` won't put x in the string, right?

Comment: In your example, what output do you expect if x is 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). And you can't use `if` statements or `for` loops inside them. What you can do is a conditional check with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

That's how you can do it:

```
console.log(`Answer: ${ (age == 18)? 'age is 18' : 'age is not 18' }`);
```